# How is type_info implemented

Tags: c++, std, typeinfo

Most c++ STL classes have easy to understand implementation. However, the `type_info` class is confusing. How does some code know the info of a class?

## Theory 1:

My first theory is that the `type_info` class gets the information from the compiler (which means that the STL has some integration with the compiler).

## Theory 2:

It could also be some obscure c++ syntax that I don’t know of, but am not too sure about this theory.

Comment: You could download the source code for GNU or CLang compilers and find out.

Comment: `type_info` is just a type defined in the *STL* library. The implementation of this type is quite straightforward: on *stdlibc++* is just a class with an internal `const char*` for storing the name. What probably is more interesting is the operator `typeid` (which returns that object). This is an operator and, thus, handled by the compiler. You can easily look at the assembly.

Comment: `type_info` class itself doesn't need integration with the compiler - it just wraps a few pieces of data. `typeid` operator is of course implemented natively in the compiler. It's also the compiler that prepares instances of `type_info` for each class, that `typeid` may then return.

Comment: That said, it's not unusual for standard library artifacts to require compiler support. E.g. some type traits (say, `std::is_trivially_copyable`) are impossible to implement otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you've basically answered the question, so you should put that information into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type_info` is just a standard library class that provides type information. Objects of this class are returned by the `typeid` operator.

Of greatest interest is not the class itself, but the RTTI (Run-Time Type Identification) implementation. This is a purely compiler dependent feature, part of the ABI (Application Binary Interface).

In brief, the compiler stores type information for each polymorphic type along with its *vtable* or *VMT* (Virtual Method Table). This information is per-type, not per-object and used by `typeid` and by `dynamic_cast`. The `type_info` class is just an interface provided to the end user, it has an internal implementation depending on the compiler.

Different compilers implement different ABIs. Modern gcc and clang compilers implement [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), which describes all the details of RTTI and the rest. Microsoft Visual C++ ABI is undocumented.

A good article that describes C++ vtables and covers RTTI: [Shahar Mike - C++ vtables](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part1/).